# Spring Boot app not working when deployed into standalone Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I've followed [this tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/). Now if I use it via Spring Boot it works, but if i try to deploy it (remove application class) on Apache Tomcat 7 I get 404 responses. I've also tried to make my own configuration - something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    public @Bean MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new Mongo("127.0.0.1", 27017), "movies");
    }

    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

It still does not work. So 2 questions.

1. how to run this on tomcat (how to make simple rest and run on tomcat)
2. how to configure mongo via annotation (just to get my database)

Note: by default it uses test vile running spring boot and I can make it work via simple controllers (instead of `@RepositoryRestResource`) but I want to able to curl `http://localhost:8080` and get response with options.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you made sure you followed the [section on traditional deployments](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) of the Boot reference documentation? From what you describe, it doesn't look like Spring Data REST or MongoDB not working but the deployment not really working at all.

The trick should be to let the main configuration class you have to implement a special interface so that the servlet container can find the configuration to bootstrap (sample taken from the reference docs):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }
}
```

`SpringBootServletInitializer` is the key aspect here as it's the type that hooks into the Servlet 3 bootstrap mechanism for traditional web apps. The reference docs also have [instructions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file-for-older-containers) of how to make a boot app work in Servlet containers prior to Servlet 3.0.

Also note, that when an app is deployed into a standalone container, it's usually not available via the root (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/`) but a dedicated context named after the WAR file deployed (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/my-app`).

Comment: extends SpringBootServletInitializer was missing. I was trying to remove this application class and put stuff in web.xml but i wanted to make it work this way because it's much easier to read. Thank you very much.

About the deployment on localhost - i was using "@RequestMapping" on "/" and it gave me response on localhost without /myapp but this was when i used web.xml and "@Controller" + I was deploying it via spring tool suit (when i run tomcat manually of course i needed /myapp)

Again thank you very much for reply.

Answer (score 1):

**Just remove** : `<scope>provided</scope>` unless you want to deploy it finally to other tomcat

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a different version of this problem that was due to the java version. All configurations were correct in the pom.

```
<properties>
    ...    
    <tomcat.version>8.0.39</tomcat.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    ...
</properties>
```

Turns out the server was running OpenJDK version 7. There were no errors in the tomcat logs on startup, but also no output from the spring application.

After upgrading the server to the Oracle JDK version 8, everything started up fine.

Comment: Useful to know. Thank you although I'm late i did not see this before in notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with a more recent Tomcat (7.0.82). After the other solutions described here didn't work out for me I was able to solve the issue by implementing another class `ServletInitializer.java`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApp.class);
    }
}
```

instead of extending `MyApp.java`:

```
...
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ...
}
```

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92ceKwUZoA0 for a complete tutorial.